# Running apk inside android app

Tags: android, apk

How to running an apk file inside android app?
I put apk file in asset directory. I have a bit information about wrapper apk and use reflection to do this.
Anyone can help?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you trying to install apk from asset ?

Comment: not install, just running apk

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ex. I have an application name A. Inside A, I put B.apk into asset dir. I want to run B.apk without install it. I mean that running directly MainActivity in B.apk

Answer (score 0):

If your app is a system application then it can done or if your inside apk file is your app then you can make that app icon hide to launcher. Suppose your app name A & you want to run B from A. B's icon is hidden to launcher. So, when your run app A then app A intent to App B for ruing. & if you don't have any control on B then you can build a application like App locker. I think you understand my Idea.

Thanks